# Trying to play steam pc games on my macbook pro

Tags: ssd, steam

So I was wondering if I put parallels on a ssd (256 GB) and kept Mac os x on a HDD and had 16 GB ram would It be good enough to play steam games.I dont care about graphics cards, Im just wondering would parallels run almost like a pc os.

Comment: Depends on what you expect and how complex the graphics are 0 also I would put the OS on a SSD as well - with 256G that is enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will run **almost** like a PC yes.

Also considering you have 16GB of Ram you are good to go! But be careful not to fill up your Hard Drive with the games you install as they can stack up your Hard Drive pretty easily.

I would suggest to install all PC games on an external Hard Drive. Since filling up the SSD could potentially slow down the performance and boot-up speed.

Comment: How measurable is the slow down?

Comment: Well it depends how much space you have on the SSD or HDD. If you have the operating system on the SSD and install games on the same SSD instead of an external or internal hard drive you will lose both performance and boot-up speed. If you go over 50% of the storage you will notice some performance issues (porbably) and longer boot up time. Depending how good your SSD/HDD is.

The more you have on the same hard drive as the operating system, the more the system has to prepare to boot.